# In Moonrise Kingdom, what is the scene after the chapel a parody of?

Tags: moonrise-kingdom

In [Moonrise Kingdom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1748122/), the scene after the "chapel" looks very, very familiar - what is it a parody of?

Part of the scene is seen in [the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7N8wkVA4_8s), from 1:43 to 1:46.

Comment: can you be more specific about what occurs in the scene?

Comment: I liked the film rather more than some of Mr. Anderson's other work, but there is a degree to which every scene in one of Wes' films looks like every other scene in a Wes Anderson film. The man simply has a distinctive visual style.

Comment: @ShaneFinneran Ah, found it in the trailer, added a link and the time. I hope that is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

To me, that scene has similar camera angle and swagger as the opening-credits shots in Reservoir Dogs when the entire group of robbers are walking together -- beginning at [00:27 in this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qBWc8FCEEM)